# Python list to np.array of counts

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Suppose we have a vector size `N=1000` and let's say we get the list `[1,1,2,2,2,100]`

I'd like to generate an np.array (or pd.Series) of size 1000 where `v[n]` is the number of times `n` appears in the list. In our example, `v[1] = 2, v[2] = 3, v[100] = 1, v=[42] = 0`

How can I do that with numpy/pandas elegantly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a list `mylist`, you can get an array of counts `mycount`:

```
N = 1000
x = np.array(mylist)
mycount = np.bincount(x, minlength=N)
```

This sorts each element in the array into bins based on its value and quantity. You can find more information on `bincount` on [this doc page](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html).

Answer (score 2):

Python has a native method for counting occurrences called `Counter` which can be used without invoking `numpy` or `pandas` if desired

```
from collections import Counter
a = [1,1,2,2,2,100]
cnts = Counter(a)
print(cnts)
# Counter({2: 3, 1: 2, 100: 1})
```

You can convert this to a list with a list comprehension:

```
N = 100
cnts_list = [cnts.get(i, 0) for i in range(N+1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) for add non exist values:

```
a = [1,1,2,2,2,100]

N = 100
a = pd.Series(a).value_counts().reindex(range(N+1), fill_value=0)
print (a)
0      0
1      2
2      3
3      0
4      0
      ..
96     0
97     0
98     0
99     0
100    1
Length: 101, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.unique` as well.

```
N = 1000
result = np.zeros(N)
idx, val = np.unique([1,1,2,2,2,100], return_counts=True)
result[idx] = val
print(result[:5])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
>>>[0. 2. 3. 0. 0.]
```

more information: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html

Answer (score 0):

### You can use Series and Group by

```py
In[1]:

import pandas as pd
my_list = [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,4,8,1000,8,8,5,5,6]

my_Serie = pd.Series(my_list)
v = my_Serie.groupby(my_list).count().to_dict()
print(v)

{1: 3, 2: 4, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 1, 8: 3, 1000: 1}
```